# save style to mapinfo Tab file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, style

When we work with Tab file in Mapinfo we can save the style directly into the Tab file.

Is there any way to save a feature layer together with a defined style into tab file in QGIS?

Comment: You can export your polyline and polygon layers to .tab format with symbology. Click "Save as" and in the export options window choose the Feature Symbology option.

Comment: But it is still impossible to save symbology of a POINT layer when exporting to .tab format even if .ttf font is used for symbology (which is used in MapInfo too) See my resent question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388797/what-is-the-difference-between-feature-symbology-and-symbol-layer-symbology-in-q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that MapInfo's styling works is unusual, in that it is per-feature.

The only way you're going to be able to do it is if you implement a plugin yourself, and it'll be fiddly, as you'll need to consider what styles are supported by MapInfo, and also implement a lookup table between MapInfo's odd numbering style for patterns and their weird colour storage method.

The short answer is that, you can't easily store MapInfo styles with QGIS.

A way I've gotten around this is using FME to process features and automatically add MI styles (this was in an SQL Server database).

Alternately, you could maintain a list of strings that are common MapInfo styles, and maintain them as attributes. (Assuming again you're working with a database table, and can edit the MI_STYLE attribute manually.)

Comment: It is possible to save simple symbology of polygon and polyline layers (but not point layer) when exporting to MapInfo .tab format https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388797/what-is-the-difference-between-feature-symbology-and-symbol-layer-symbology-in-q