# What is the difference between Feature Symbology and Symbol Layer Symbology in QGIS? How to save symbology when exporting a point layer to .tab format

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, export, tab

What is the difference between those two variants of symbology export. I tried to export a point layer from QGIS to .tab format using both of them. "MapInfo Cartographic" True Type Font .ttf was used for symbology. The same font is used in MapInfo too.

[image]

Export settings:

[image]

But none of those two variants are successful. Why can't I export a layer with symbology? And what is the difference between "Feature Symbology" and "Symbol Layer Symbology" options? (see the above picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the Swiss QGIS user group [(Link to relevant page)](https://www.qgis.ch/fr/projets/export-dxf) says about similar export option about DXF, I assume the same logic apply to MapInfo TAB export :

> **Different symbology export options:**
>
> - No symbology : just one single geometry per feature, default symbology (mostly black)
> - Feature symbology : one single geometry per feature, only first symbol level (no complete reproduction of original symbology)
> - Symbol layer symbology : depending on the symbology, the same geometry is exported several times on top of each other, for each
>   symbol level    defined. Better suited for more complete reproduction
>   of complex    symbology

As for why you can't export a layer with symbology is down to how different software have different symbology option/capacity and how good is the driver to translate between those. As a rule of thumb the more complex the symbology the less likely it will translate between format.

In your particular case and if your screenshots is representative of your whole symbology it will be trivial to export with no symbology and reaply the same  font symbol in MapInfo

Comment: @KVO I'm not a MapInfo user so I'm not used to these problem but a quick internet search indicate that transferring symbology between QGIS and MapInfo is not straightforward (I find some solution going from MapInfo to QGIS, but unfortunately not the other way), let hope somebody else come with a solution for you.