# Exporting MapInfo TAB file with symbology using Processing Toolbox or PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, layers, export, tab

In the newer versions of QGIS it's possible to export a layer as a Mapinfo Tab file and include the Feature Symbology. Does anyone know if you can access this as part of the 'Save Vector Features To File' algorithm or PyQGIS?

[image: symbology export]

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [`symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorFileWriter.html#a1aac90d30d811d2888d1aab4098ad63c) parameter when writing and it will keep its symbology when opened in MapInfo.

```py
from os.path import abspath
from qgis.utils import iface 

_vlayer = iface.activeLayer()

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(
    layer=_vlayer,
    fileName=abspath("D:/test_file.tab"),
    fileEncoding="utf-8",
    driverName="MapInfo File",
    symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology
    )
```

Comment: have you checked it with a point layer?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work with points but it does work with polygons. Haven't checked lines yet. That's a pain, as it will read MapInfo point symbology into QGIS

Comment: I have asked a question about it 2 years ago. It is here:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388797/what-is-the-difference-between-feature-symbology-and-symbol-layer-symbology-in-q

Comment: is it possible to export a layer from QGIS to MapInfo .MIF format retaining MapInfo symbology by a PyQGIS script? MIF format is human readable and a .MIF file can be edited by simple text editor such as blocknote or Notepad++